# DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, model-view-controller, datatables

I am using jquery Datatables and I am getting this error: DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. This is MVC app. Data is from MSQL database. have no error on chrome's console. Maybe it is a syntax problem?
Here is my .jsp file:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script>
        function confirmDelete(id) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this cost?")) {
                window.location.href = "/cost/delete/" + id;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../resources/js/datatable.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:80%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>MPK</th>
        <th>Account</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Payment</th>
        <th>Invoice Number</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Edit</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="costs" items="${allcosts}">
        <tr>
            <td>${costs.id}</td>
            <td>${costs.salesDate.toString()}</td>
            <td>${costs.mpk.code}</td>
            <td>${costs.account.code}</td>
            <td>${costs.client.name}</td>
            <td>${costs.amount.toString()}</td>
            <td>${costs.description.toString()}</td>
            <td>${costs.payment.type}</td>
            <td>${costs.invoiceNumber.toString()}</td>
            <td>${costs.department.name}</td>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="confirmDelete(${costs.id}, '${costs.id}')">Delete</a></td>
            <td><a href="/cost/update/${costs.id}">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>

<spring:url value="/report/?type=xls" var="xlsURL"/>
<a href="${xlsURL }">Download Excel</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my .js file:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength": 5,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/cost/all",
            "columns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {"data": "Delete"},
                {"data": "Edit"}
            ]
        }  });
});
```

How can I solve this problem? I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following initialization code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#example').DataTable({
      pageLength: 5
   });
});
```